# How to calculate percentage for number of values in a column in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column called text and another called 'categories' with three values "positive", "negative", "neutral".

How can I calculate the percentage of each of the text values in category?
for example if I had 3 rows, 1 row is positive, 1 row is negative and 1 row is neutral what query will produce 33% positive 33% negative and 33% neutral?

This is the stage I got to...

```
SELECT COUNT(category), category  FROM tweets GROUP BY category
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it

```sql
select category, count, count/total percent
  from 
  (
    select category, count(category) count
      from tweets 
     group by category
  ) c JOIN (
    select count(*) total
      from tweets
  ) t
```

Output:

```
+----------+-------+---------+
| category | count | percent |
+----------+-------+---------+
| negative |     1 |  0.3333 |
| neutral  |     1 |  0.3333 |
| positive |     1 |  0.3333 |
+----------+-------+---------+
```

---

> ...would it be possible to return just 33% not 0.3333?

```sql
select category, count, round(count / total * 100) percent
  from 
  (
    select category, count(category) count
      from tweets 
     group by category
  ) c JOIN (
    select count(*) total
      from tweets
  ) t
```

```
+----------+-------+---------+
| category | count | percent |
+----------+-------+---------+
| negative |     1 |      33 |
| neutral  |     1 |      33 |
| positive |     1 |      33 |
+----------+-------+---------+
```

*If you want to add `%` you can use do `concat(round(count / total * 100), '%')` but I would strongly suggest to do it (any sort of formatting) in the client code.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer @peterm would it be possible to return just 33% not 0.3333?

Answer (score 1):

As a note, I think this is much more simply written using a single subquery:

```
select t.category, count(*) / t.total,       -- number
       concat(100 * count(*) / t.total, '%') -- string
from tweets t join
     (select count(*) as total) t
group by category;
```

If you know there are only three categories, I'd put them in one row:

```
select avg(category = 'positive') as p_positive,
       avg(category = 'negative') as p_negative
       avg(category = 'neutral') as p_neutral
from tweets t;
```

This query uses the MySQL feature that a boolean expression is treated as an integer in a numeric context, with "1" for true and "0" for false.

Answer (score -2):

Just a small modification to your current query:

```
SELECT COUNT(category)/COUNT(*), category FROM tweets GROUP BY category
```

Comment: `COUNT(category)/COUNT(*)` will always return `1` assuming `category` doesn't contain nulls